# Flow type system in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, flowtype

i start to use Flow in my React application and i have question about the type system.

I have a stateless component like this

```
export type LinkProps = {
 to: string,
 icon: React$Element<any>,
 style: Object
}

const Link = ({
  to,
  icon,
  style
}: LinkProps) => (
   <sample>

   </sample>
)
```

And another component where override some props

```
const NavLink = (props: LinkProps) => <Link icon={<Icon />} {...props} />
```

So, if i use the Link component directly i have the Flow type system but is not the case with the NavLink component.

Why i can use the NavLink component without respect the type system?

Comment: Are you saying that you can pass in whatever you want to `NavLink` and Flow doesn't pick that up?

Comment: Yes, this is the point. If i use the NavLink in the same file where i declare it the type system work, but not if i use the NavLink in Sidebar component, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to add `// @flow` to the top of the file where you are using the `NavLink` component